# java error in for loop show error not a statement

Tags: java, encryption, logic, blowfish

i have one function but in **for loop** show error **not a statement**
check this following code

```
byte[] block = new byte[8];
byte[] block2 = new byte[8];
int b = fin.read(block);

for (; b != -1; ((b > 0 ? 1 : 0) & (b < 8 ? 1 : 0)) != 0) {
    blow.engineUpdate(block, 0, 8, block2, 0);
    fout.write(block2);
    b = fin.read(block);
    continue;
    block[(b - 1)] = 0;
    b++;
}
```

in this line: for (; b != -1; ((b > 0 ? 1 : 0) & (b < 8 ? 1 : 0)) != 0)

and this line : block[(b - 1)] = 0;

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the precise compile errors you are getting?

Comment: The third component inside the `for` parentesis `((b > 0 ? 1 : 0) & (b < 8 ? 1 : 0)) != 0` is a condition but should be a statement.

Comment: The, or at least **a**, problem with  `block[(b - 1)] = 0;` is that it's unreachable because of the immediately preceding unguarded `continue;`

Answer (score 0):

`for (<variable>; <condition>; <increment>) { ... }`

So in your case, variable is empty.
condition is b != -1
but, third parameter should be something like b++ not a boolean expression.